# Why import androidx.room.Entity; is not recognized, how to use roomdb annotations?

Tags: android, android-studio, annotations

Why `import androidx.room.Entity;` is not recognized in my class file in Android studio?
neither any of these @Entity, @ColunInfo  etc.  I am using Android studio and Java

I have added the following in the dependencies

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.paragroom"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    def room_version = "2.4.3"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to sync your project after adding dependencies? If yes, then try invalidating the cache.

Comment: Thanks, Now it is working. Sync was the problem... for some reason sync didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't sure about your problem. Here is everything about room in my gradle (I'm using kotlin)

```
    //room
    def room_version = "2.4.2"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    kapt  "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

Did you try invalidate cache & restart IDE?

Answer (score 0):

In gradle "Toggle Offline mode" should be unchecked